# Can there be a situation where one regression model gives lower RMSE than the other but also lower R-squared?

Tags: r, regression, r-squared, rms

Consider the following scenario where you use the same data `X` (the same number of predictors `p`, same number of observations `n`) to predict a continuous outcome `y`, in 2 different regression models (e.g. Linear Regression and Random Forests).
For both models you calculate `RMSE` and `R-squared` (assume simple correlation between y and y-hat, squared).

You get:

```
RMSE1 < RMSE2

R-squared1 < R-squared2
```

Could someone explain if this scenario is possible and how it occurs?
A simple simulation in `R` could also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may arise if the regression model is nonlinear. Consider the following true data

```
0.6
0.55
0.3
0.24
0.22
```

With model 1 predicting

```
0.82
0.72
0.55
0.29
0.1
```

and model 2

```
0.7
0.58
0.51
0.2
0.09
```

$R^2$ for Model 1 is 0.8448 while for Model 2 is 0.7866.

However, Model 1 has higher RMS error, at 0.1770 but Model 2 only has RMSE of 0.1212

This happens because $R^2$ is only really valid for linear regression models (and data).